# Where can I find analysis on the convergence rate of RMSE for various algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, convergence, nonparametric-regression

I am looking for convergence rates of the RMSE of various machine learning algorithms and conditions for them. Essentially, I would like to find something of the form
$$E[ |\hat{f}(x) - f(x)|^2] = o(1/n^\alpha)$$

is it possible to find something like that?